# Does any app server vendor implement JSR 88: Java EE Application Deployment

Tags: java, deployment, jakarta-ee, installation

I am wondering if JSR 88 is a standard part of Java EE 5 and if there are any app server vendors implementing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a standard in Java EE (at least in 6). It has not gained much vendor support though, hence there a  *proposal* to remove it from Java EE 7.

Source: [**Beginning Java EE 6 Platform with GlassFish 3: from novice to professional** by Antonio Goncalves](http://books.google.co.za/books?id=GxrTgSHRIroC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=app+servers+that+are+JSR+88+compliant&source=bl&ots=11MfDbyRyv&sig=LsLjufztToCLSkZ-nUYys4hNSAo&hl=en&ei=0AHcTPvvFsmWOsu0sKMJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false).